# invoking a third party app through asp.net/C# code- UI gets "stuck"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam trying to write a webpage where iam invoking a third part app (.exe) from the code 
using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("app.exe")
```

The app fires and it starts to open up the GUI but gets "stuck" after about 3-4 seconds and just sits there.. Its not an app issue as it runs fine when I run it through the local admin account on the web-server. I also tried invoking this app through the admin account using

```
Start(
string fileName,
string userName,
SecureString password,
string domain)
```

but that didnt help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You definitely *do not* want to allow your webpage to execute arbitrary applications on your web server. That is a massive security hole.

Comment: understood. in our case however this code is run under a tightly controlled environment so security is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to set some initialization before you run it, and not run it with the default settings that are not for the web, so try this code:

```
   Process compiler = new Process();

    // Make sure that the application.exe can be found
    compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\app.exe";

    compiler.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    // here I run it
    compiler.Start();

    compiler.StandardInput.Flush();
    compiler.StandardInput.Close();

    // here I get the output
    string cReadOutput = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    compiler.WaitForExit();
    compiler.Close();
```

Comment: perhaps I should have clarified- I did set all the parameters as you suggested but the behavior still persists.

Comment: @swellcode if you call the WaitForExit, and then reach the close, then the application have been close. Or where is stop and waits on that steps ?

Comment: @swellcode Where ? in witch line ? Maybe is waiting for an enter or something ?

Comment: Aristos, it pretty much sits there and gets stuck (GUI doesnt load completely.. it tries to load and sits there with partially rendered windows etc) as if its fighting for hardware resources, of which plenty is available. I tried my code even with Internet Explorer (iexplore.exe) and still same issue.. the code you suggested doesnt produce any error and executes, however the app fired with this code (via asp) gets stuck..